# Cs50 pset1-cash expected "18\n", not "22\n"

Tags: c, cs50

I'm a begginer in C and I'm taking cs50. I'm having trouble with pset1/cash. I have no idea what is wrong with my code. The program first asks the user how much change is owed and then spits out the minimum number of coins with which said change can be made. It works fine with most inputs but when I check it I get **expected "18\n", not "22\n"**  Please, what do I need to change?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    float change;
    int cents, cents2, cents3, cents4;
    int total = 0;

    //Ask for user input and check
    do
    {
        change = get_float("How much change?\n");
    }
    while (change < 0);
    change = (change * 100) / 0.01;

    //Multiply the float numbers
    if (change < 1)
    {
        change *= 100;
    }
    else if (change < 10)
    {
        change *= 10;
    }

    //Change to int
    cents = change;

    //How many quarters
    while (cents >= 2500)
    {
        cents -= 2500;
        total++;
    }
    cents2 = cents;

    //How many dimes
    while (cents2 >= 1000)
    {
        cents2 -= 1000;
        total++;
    }
    cents3 = cents2;

    //How many nickels
    while (cents3 >= 500)
    {
        cents3 -= 500;
        total++;
    }
    cents4 = cents3;

    //How many pennies
    while (cents4 >= 100)
    {
        cents4 -= 100;
        total++;
    }

    printf("%i\n", total);
}
```

**Edit:** I have finally found my error. In this line: change = (change * 100) / 0.01; I added 0.01 to it and now it works.
**change = (change * 10000) + 0.01;**

Comment: Don't use floating points for currency, that never works because of the nature of floating points. Use integers (times 100) instead, instead of using 0.01 for 1 cent, use 1 for 1 cent, and 100 for 1 dollar.

Comment: What, exactly, is `change = (change * 100) / 0.01;` supposed to accomplish?  Are you intending to multiply your `change` value by 10,000?  As to your specific issue, quarters are not the largest denomination of change - you forgot about half-dollars.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The assignment actually specifies that half dollars should not be used, sorry I forgot to mention that. And about the multiplication... to be honest  I'm not sure why I used this exact value, I just tried a bunch of things x.x but if the user input is something like "75" it should be read as 75 dollars, so it returns 300. And this value worked for this purpose, but I still can't fix the problem when the input is "4.2", or any other number like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the round function to round up your numbers. In this part of your code, you need to add the round function.

```c
change = (change * 100) / 0.01;
```

It has to be like this:

```c
cents = round(change * 100);
```

This will round up the numbers to the nearest wholeIf you have other such problems, you can use a debugger such as debug50, in which you put a breakpoint by clicking in the right of the line number, then in your terminal window(the one where you execute clang) you should type:

```c
~/pset1/cash/ $ debug50 ./cash
```

Or whatever your program is called. This will open the debugger and inside it you will find all the variables and what they are equal to. Press on the button next to the play button to move one line of code forward.

P.S
There are lots of questions exactly like yours. Just search your problem into the Search... at the top of your screen and I daresay you'll find an answer to your problem.

Comment: I doubt there is much benefit to provide identical answers to a set of duplicate questions that have been asked years ago.

Comment: Sorry I just know that they are different people and what to help everyone I can.

Comment: If they took the CS50 course in 2017 or 2018 they probably solved it by now. ;)

Comment: Yeah didn't think 'bout that. Thou if someone else searches the answer when they have the same problem as in the question it might prove useful :)